# Insert form data with 2 image fields in db

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload, image-uploading

i've searched after this but can't find anything clear.
I' have a form with 2 input file fields, i need all data to be inserted.
I'dont want a multifile upload, i need each input file to be seperated.
I like the code above cause it renames each files.
I've tried this

```
`$host="hst";
$databasename="nme";
$user="usr";
$pass="pwd";
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/


$conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

if($conn)
{
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($databasename, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
}
else
{
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
$name     = $_POST["name"] ;
//email:
 $email = $_POST["email"] ;
 //description:
 $description        = $_POST["description"] ;
 //partie:
  $partie       = $_POST["partie"] ;

function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
    switch($imagetype)
   {
        case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
       case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
       case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
       case 'image/png': return '.png';
       default: return false;
   }
 }

if (!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {

$file_name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
$temp_name=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$imgtype=$_FILES["image"]["type"];
$ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
$imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
$target_path = "images/assets/syltattoo/Emails/".$imagename;
    if (!empty($_FILES["image2"]["name"])) {

$file_name2=$_FILES["image2"]["name"];
$temp_name2=$_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name2"];
$imgtype2=$_FILES["image2"]["type2"];
$ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
$imagename2=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
$target_path2 = "images/assets/syltattoo/Emails/".$imagename2;

if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
$query_upload="INSERT INTO `modx_demandes`(image, image2, name, email, description, partie) VALUES 

('".$target_path."','".$target_path2."','$name', '$email', '$description', '$partie')";
mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());
}else{

 exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 

}}`
```

And here is the form:

```
<form action="demandes-de-tatouage.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="name"><label for="name">Nom:</label></div>
<div class="controls"><input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="name" value="" /></div>
<div id="name"><label for="name">Email:</label></div>
<div class="controls"><input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="email" value="" /></div>

<div id="description"><label for="description">Description:</label></div>
<div class="controls"><input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="description" value="" /></div>
<div id="name"><label for="name">Partie du corps:</label></div>
<div class="controls"><input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="partie" value="" /></div>
<div>
<label for="image">Envoyez vos images</label></div>
<input id="image" name="image" type="file" value="" maxlength="100000" /> 
<input id="image2" name="image2" type="file" value="" maxlength="100000" /> 

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Envoyer" /></form>
```

I tried to integrate the second image2 field, but it saves the same result for image1 and image2 in database. Is someone could help me with this script to make something that I can use with multiple input fields image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did some typos in your script (you were getting the same extension from `$imgtype`) and you weren't using the original filenames when you inserted them in database. Furthemore, you weren't saving the second file anywhere. Does this code works for you ?

```
<?php
$host = "hst";
$databasename = "nme";
$user = "usr";
$pass = "pwd";
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/


$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if ($conn) {
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($databasename, $conn);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
    }
} else {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
$name = $_POST["name"];
//email:
$email = $_POST["email"];
//description:
$description = $_POST["description"];
//partie:
$partie = $_POST["partie"];

function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
{
    if (empty($imagetype)) {
        return false;
    }
    switch ($imagetype) {
        case 'image/bmp':
            return '.bmp';
        case 'image/gif':
            return '.gif';
        case 'image/jpeg':
            return '.jpg';
        case 'image/png':
            return '.png';
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

if (!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {

    $file_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $temp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $ext = GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename = $file_name . "-" .  date("d-m-Y") . "-" . time() . $ext;
    $target_path = "images/assets/syltattoo/Emails/" . $imagename;
    if (!empty($_FILES["image2"]["name"])) {

        $file_name2 = $_FILES["image2"]["name"];
        $temp_name2 = $_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"];
        $imgtype2 = $_FILES["image2"]["type"];
        $ext2 = GetImageExtension($imgtype2);
        $imagename2 = $file_name2 . "-" . date("d-m-Y") . "-" . time() . $ext2;
        $target_path2 = "images/assets/syltattoo/Emails/" . $imagename2;

        if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path) && move_uploaded_file($temp_name2, $target_path2)) {
            $query_upload = "INSERT INTO `modx_demandes`(image, image2, name, email, description, partie) VALUES

('" . $target_path . "','" . $target_path2 . "','$name', '$email', '$description', '$partie')";
            mysql_query(
                $query_upload
            ) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> " . mysql_error());
        } else {

            exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Here is some refactored code. This code should also work even if the user didn't send any image.

```
<?php
$host = "hst";
$databasename = "nme";
$user = "usr";
$pass = "pwd";
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/


$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if ($conn) {
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($databasename, $conn);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
    }
} else {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
$name = $_POST["name"];
//email:
$email = $_POST["email"];
//description:
$description = $_POST["description"];
//partie:
$partie = $_POST["partie"];

function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
{
    if (empty($imagetype)) {
        return false;
    }
    switch ($imagetype) {
        case 'image/bmp':
            return '.bmp';
        case 'image/gif':
            return '.gif';
        case 'image/jpeg':
            return '.jpg';
        case 'image/png':
            return '.png';
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

function uploadImage($image) {
    if(!empty($image["name"])) {
        $file_name = $image["name"];
        $temp_name = $image["tmp_name"];
        $imgtype = $image["type"];
        $ext = GetImageExtension($imgtype);
        $imagename = $file_name . "-" . date("d-m-Y") . "-" . time() . $ext;
        $target_path = "images/assets/syltattoo/Emails/" . $imagename;
        if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
            return $target_path;
        }
        exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    }
    return null;
}

$target_path = uploadImage($_FILES["image"]);
$target_path2 = uploadImage($_FILES["image2"]);

$query_upload = "INSERT INTO `modx_demandes`(image, image2, name, email, description, partie) VALUES ('" . $target_path . "','" . $target_path2 . "','$name', '$email', '$description', '$partie')";
mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> " . mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: No it does not, i still have same result for both fields.

Comment: Is it possible to see your HTLM form ?

Comment: Ok, you shouldn't target `type2` and `tmp_name2` in your code for the image2 but `type` and `tmp_name`. I just edited my answer with this fix. Can you try it ? If it doesn't work, can you echo the `$target_name` and the `$target_name2` just before insertion ?

Comment: It partialy works, no data are recorded if the two image fields are empty.

Comment: I don't understand. Is your comment cynical :) ?

Comment: Not at all, i need user to be abble to send form data even with empty image fields. I'm a total noob at php, thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: What images would you save if the user does not send them ? Do you want to have some default images ?

Comment: No look at the code there is name, email, description, partie fields as well.
If my user fill all fields except image and image2 and then send the form nothing is inserted in database. Not sur to be clear here.

Comment: I just added a section in my answer above with the type of handling you want. I coudldn't test it though. Can you try it and tell me if it's what you were expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

that's because its the same date and time for your file name ... put

`$imagename2=date("d-m-Y")."-".time() . "-2" .$ext;`

for the second file name

you also need to move the second file

`if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path) && move_uploaded_file($temp_name2, $target_path2)) {`